# "Share me" or "Share with me"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions

I heard people saying:

> Can you please share me the slides?

or

> Can you share me the note, etc.?

I think it should be:

> Can you please share the slides with me?

or

> Can you share the notes with me?

which one is correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: related: [explain me vs explain to me](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/which-one-is-correct-explain-me-or-explain-to-me), [I'll open you the door](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door/90532#90532)

Comment: I've witnessed usage of "share me the information" but the person who used it was not a native English speaker and often does not use prepositions where they should be used. He would also use the following Can you explain me the diagram?
Mention him that I am not going.

Answer (score 4):

"share me" indicates that it's you who gets shared. Usually that's not something you see outside of slavery and sexual relations ;)
So yes, you're quite correct that it's incorrect to use the term in the context you show.

But as with so many things, it's becoming ever more common in the day and age where cellphone text messages and twitter messages are rewriting the rules of English grammar (and spelling).

Answer (score 2):

Contra all the other answers: this is a normal, though unusual, example of a standard construction in English, where a bitransitive verb (one with a direct and an indirect object) has two different realisations:

> Give the book to me <=> give me the book
>
> Show the picture to her <=> show her the picture
>
> Make a cup of tea for me <=> make me a cup of tea

The examples show that the indirect object can be with *to* or *for*. Examples with *with* are rare, which is why I described this as unusual.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, 
share with you something
OR
share something with you

constructs are correct. The latter being more colloquial.

sharing you is to distribute(or well, share) you with something/one

Comment: No _share with you something_ is questionably grammatical, and certainly not idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

The expression 'Please share me the slides' is ungrammatical.

You can however say: 'Please share the slides'.

It does not however make it clear as to with whom the person should share the slides. For that you need to say: 'Please share the slides with me', or 'Please share the slides with John'.

Comment: I believe "Can you please share me the + noun" is heard/ dialect/slang. Have you ever heard this type of construction?

Comment: 'Share' does not figure in the list of over 70 English verbs which can be used ditransitively / benefactively / ... (ie + IO + DO, or similar) I've compiled (from other lists, eg those mentioned [here](http://www.englishpage.net/showthread.php?16089-Ditransitive-verbs)).

Answer (score 0):

In the ordinary course of things, *share with* is proper and correct, and using *share* without its accompanying *with* when talking about a closed transaction (that is, when there is a definite someone to share with) is indisputably wrong. It becomes just a little more difficult to make absolute declarations in the context of online interactions and social media, since *share* has acquired a slightly different meaning there.

I don't like it, and though I may have acquired a bit of a reputation as an anti-prescriptivist, my dislike may simply be something that can be written off as an artifact of age and incipient curmudgeonry. Time and usage will decide the issue, not anything anyone has written or read in authoritative books, nor even the habit of usage prior to the ubiquitous "Share" button. While the issue (and others like it) sorts itself out, you can expect to hear things that make you uncomfortable. Language changes, and sometimes tries to change but fails, and there is no way to predict which way this will go.

Comment: Even when a share button is used, I usually see it described as _share <this article> **with** you friends_, or _share on Twitter_, or something like that. I have never seen _share your friends_ in the sense of _share this with your friends_ (yet?). The world may not be ending yet :)

Comment: @oerkelens - It's the "share on *X*" variant that's causing the  problem. But then I still have problems with *boot* as a verb meaning *to cause a device to restart, pulling itself up by its own bootstraps, as it were*.

Comment: Doesn't that verb come from the idea that you _kick_ the appliance into action? I remember applying the verb literally with satisfying results when I was told to boot my computer.